# Adding subElement at a specific location with xml.dom.minidom (appendChild)

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I intend to insert a sub element at a specified location. However, I do not know how to do that using **appendChild** in **xml.dom** 
Here is my xml code:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<VOD>
  <root>
 <ab>sdsd
  <pp>pras</pp>
  <ps>sinha</ps>
 </ab>
 <ab>prashu</ab>
 <ab>sakshi</ab>
 <cd>dfdf</cd>
  </root>
  <root>
 <ab>pratik</ab>
  </root>
  <root>
 <ab>Mum</ab>
  </root>
</VOD>
```

I would like to insert another sub element "new" in first "root" element just before the "cd" tag. The result should look like this:

```
<ab>prashu</ab>
<ab>sakshi</ab>
<new>Anydata</new>
<cd>dfdf</cd>
```

The code I used for this is:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as m

doc = m.parse("file_notes.xml")
root=doc.getElementsByTagName("root")

valeurs = doc.getElementsByTagName("root")[0]
element = doc.createElement("new")
element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Anydata"))
valeurs.appendChild(element)

doc.writexml(open("newxmlfile.xml","w"))
```

In what way can I achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance..!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using **insertBefore** instead. Something along these lines:

```
element = doc.createElement("new")
element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Anydata"))
cd = doc.getElementsByTagName("cd")[0]
cd.parentNode.insertBefore(element, cd)
```

To insert new nodes based on an index you can just do:

```
 cd_list = doc.getElementsByTagName("cd")
 cd_list[0].parentNode.insertBefore(element, cd_list[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. insertBefore works perfectly... Although it would have been much more convenient if I could be able to add sub elements at a specific index value. Is there any way I could do that..???

Comment: Yes you can insert based on an index value. I'll update the answer.

Comment: <new>Anydata</new>
<cd>dfdf</cd>

I am getting this in the same line(single line) , but I need to get it one after another (meaning <cd>dfdf</cd> should be in a newline).. how ? @Garett

Comment: @Legolas The writexml method added additional parameters which controls formatting (pretty print). https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.writexml